# Prägnantes Wort für das hörbare Einatmen, wenn einem "der Atem stockt"

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es einen Begriff, der das nach Luft schnappen bezeichnet, das man macht, wenn man aufgrund einer Schockstarre seinen eigentlichen Atemrhythmus unterbricht?
Mir fällt nur die Phrase "der Atem stockt" ein. Mir geht's aber eigentlich um die Beschreibung des Einatmens selbst, einschließlich des Sounds, den man dabei macht, und nicht um die Unterbrechung der Atmung.

Es gibt für so viele Varianten des Ein- oder Ausatmens Begriffe. Einige kommen diesem Atemreflex selbst auch schon nahe *(Keuchen, Japsen, Schnaufen, Lechzen),* treffen ihn aber meiner Meinung nicht ganz.

Comment: Meinst Du eher einen intensiven [Glottisschlag](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmloser_glottaler_Plosiv#Der_Glottisschlag_im_Deutschen) mit anschließendem kurzen Ausatmen oder ein tiefes, rasches Einatmen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Hatte gedacht, die Phrase "der Atem stockt" würde es auf den Punkt bringen. Aber wahrscheinlich gibt es tatsächlich verschieden Formen der Reaktion, wenn einem der Atem stockt. – Ich glaube, "tiefes, rasches Einatmen" triffts schon gut. Man öffnet den Mund sehr weit, nicht ganz so extrem wie beim Gähnen, und atmet durch diesen ein. Lässt ihn dann für die Weile der Schockstarre geöffnet, atmen aber nicht weiter ein, sondern hält den Atem an.

Comment: Prima Frage! Ich vermute, Du wünschst Dir eine deutsche Entsprechung für "gasp" - glaube aber, dass es da nichts derart Prägnantes gibt... Zu "lechzen": Das klingt zwar lautmalerisch, beschreibt aber eigentlich keinen physischen, sondern einen mentalen Vorgang, der nicht unbedingt mit einem Geräusch verbunden ist, oder?

Comment: @Mac Richtig. Aus der Suche nach einer Übersetzung für "a gasp (of horror)" ist diese Frage hervorgegangen. – Ich hab gerade "Lechzen" nochmals nachgeschlagen und Wiktionary definiert es als "heftig nach etw. verlangen, das dringend benötigt wird". Nicht nur im Moment des Schocks verlangen/benötigen wir Luft, sondern auch wenn wir uns körperlich verausgabt haben. Insofern habe ich gelegentlich schon "nach Luft lechzen" gehört. Und eine jegliche stärke Atmung ist hörbar. Reduziert auf den Kontext denke ich, dass es durchaus gelistet werden kann. Prinzipiell ist dein Einwand aber berechtigt.

Comment: Der Liste der nicht so ganz passenden Wörter hätte ich noch *Ächzen* bzw. *Ächzer* hinzuzufügen.

Comment: Möchtest du [diese Zeichnung](https://twitter.com/LuWrites/status/504698550987784193) übersetzen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein einziges prägnantes Wort für das Einatmen in der Schrecksekunde ist mir nicht geläufig. Vermutlich subsumieren wir diese unwillkürliche Reaktion neben allen anderen [Schreckreaktionen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreck) bereits in der Bezeichnung *Schreck*.

Um das Luftholen vor dem Stocken des Atems zu umschreiben, fallen mir folgende Formulierungen ein, die man zur Präzisierung noch mit "vor Schreck" ergänzen kann:

> - (Vor Schreck) **nach** Luft holen/schnappen/ringen
> - tiefes Luftholen (vor Schreck)

Ein sehr schönes, vom Aussterben bedrohtes Adjektiv, das in diesem Zusammenhang gut passt, ist *[jäh](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=j%C3%A4h)*:

> - Er holte jäh nach Luft, als der wütende Hund um die Ecke schoss.

Comment: An "vor Schreck nach Luft holen/schnappen" hatte ich auch gedacht, nicht zuletzt hatte ich die Phrase "nach Luft schnappen" auch in meiner Frage verwendet. Ich hatte nur gehofft, dass es sozusagen einen Begriff gibt, der genau das zusammenfasst. Die Idee mit "jäh" find ich nicht schlecht. Auf jeden Fall +1 :)

Comment: @Em1: wäre mir das nicht *jäh* eingefallen, hätte ich keine Antwort gewagt ;)

Answer (score 2):

Umgangssprachlich kann man "Schnappatmung" verwenden, auch wenn der Begriff medizinisch etwas anderes meint.

Answer (score 2):

Als Erstes würde mir da Folgendes einfallen:

> "Huch!"

[(Nachweis)](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41kf7oTvwWL._SY300_.jpg)